# Is there any other episodes of Naruto after Episode 220 before Naruto Shippuden Episode 1?

Tags: naruto

I watched all *Naruto* episodes on Netflix. I want to know if episode 220 leads right into *Naruto Shippuden*. I only watched a few minutes of episode 1 in *Shippuden*, but just watching it, I feel like I'm missing more episodes that lead into *Shippuden*.

Is there anymore *Naruto* episodes after Episode 220? Like, do they show Pervy Sage actually training Naruto or does his path of training leads into *Shippuden*?

Answer (score 2):

No, you haven't missed any episodes. There is a time skip between the end of *Naruto* and the beginning of *Shippuden*, where Naruto goes off and trains with Jiraiya and the other characters do various other things as well, some of which are shown in flashbacks but most are just referred to.

Answer (score 0):

There will be reference episodes regarding training and Naruto's growth in the future parts of *Shippuden*. They even pop-up just as filler episodes between an interesting plot through the series up until about episode 300 or so.